# how to hide columns in ASP.NET webform

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my PrinterPackage.**aspx** file i have the following **'User Control'**:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/ProvisionControls/DeferredTaxRollforwardControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc9" TagName="DeferredTaxesRollforwardControl" %> 
   ...
   ...
 <div>
    <uc9:DeferredTaxesRollforwardControl ID="DeferredTaxesRollforwardControl1" runat="server" />
 </div>
```

which calls the control file 'DeferredTaxRollforwardControl.**ascx**' that contains my table defined as follows:

```
<table style="width: 4600px; border-spacing:0px;" border="0" frame="hsides" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">

<tr id = "tblTempDiff"> //want to import this


<td style="width:7.6%;" width="2px;" class="paintYellowTotalLeftBold">
    Grand Total Current
</td>
<td style="width:2.8%;" width="2px;" class="paintYellowTotalBold">
    <asp:Label ID="lblGrandTotalUnadjustedBeginningBalance" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</td>
... and more <td>
```

I am trying to display the table and also hide some of the columns using the following code in my PrinterPackage.**aspx.cs** file :

```
 TableRow row = DeferredTaxesRollforwardControl1.FindControl("tblTempDiff") as TableRow;
        row.Cells[0].Visible = true;
        row.Cells[1].Visible = true;
        row.Cells[2].Visible = true;
        row.Cells[3].Visible = true;
        row.Cells[4].Visible = true;
        row.Cells[5].Visible = true;
        row.Cells[6].Visible = true;
        row.Cells[7].Visible = true;
        row.Cells[8].Visible = true;
        row.Cells[9].Visible = false;
        row.Cells[10].Visible = false;
        row.Cells[11].Visible = false;
        row.Cells[12].Visible = false;
```

But, this doesn't seem to pick up the table row **tblTempDiff** and gives me a null value instead. How can i import the data from the TableRow **tblTempDiff** into **row** and then hide whatever columns i want to hide?

**Please ask me questions if you need more information, as i know i am not the best person when it comes to explaining my questions.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code behind cannot see the `<tr>` you created because it's not a server control. Add the `runat="server"` attribute to the `<tr>`:

```
<tr id="tblTempDiff" runat="server">
```

And use [`System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablerow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `TableRow`. Two different things.

Comment: even after including the runat="server", it still doesn't fill my TableRow 'row'. Any other way i can implement the same thing? can you give me an example maybe?

Comment: Is it still null? Or are the cells just empty?

Comment: its still showing me null as the value for 'row' when i debug it. and when it tries to execute the visible = false, it gives me a null exception.

Comment: can i use the  'Label ID="lblGrandTotalUnadjustedBeginningBalance"', in any way since i am trying to hide this column?

Comment: Check my edit. Use System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow instead of TableRow and see how that goes.

Comment: i have a follow up question to this.. can i somehow set the width for the entire row? i know i can do that with gridviews but can i do that with this tablerow?

Comment: Just for this row? Or do you mean the entire table?

Comment: just for this row. Basically i have a main table which contains gridviews and then at the end of the table (last <tr> ) the totals and calculations from the gridviews above it. so i just want to make the width of this last row to match the gridviews.

Comment: i forgot to say, each cell in the last row needs to line up with the gridview columns above them. please help in any way

Comment: If you want the cells to line up, it might be better to change the width per cell. I believe `HtmlTableCell`, which you get when you call `row.Cells[X]`, has a Width property.

Comment: that doesnt seem to work somehow, i even have the "runat = "server"" at the table <td> so that it is picked up but it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

@user1319424: Rather than already creating table, use place holder and then create dynamic table and bind that table to a placeholder.

Refer below link:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=135

Comment: i cannot change the existing tables or create a new dynamic table since i am adding on a feature to an already existing code and don't want to recreate what is already available to me. Any other way i can probably do this?