# How to set width of a html tablerow in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is a follow up question to the following question link:

[how to hide columns in ASP.NET webform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112112/how-to-hide-columns-in-asp-net-webform)

following the answer that i got from the above link, i am using

```
 System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow
```

i want to set the width of the entire row. How can i do this in C#? any other idea/way you can suggest, please let me know.

if you have any more questions, please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Set width on the table, not the row.

Comment: i am pulling the table from another page on the website. And i don't want to change the table properties on that page. is there a way i can change the row/table width only for the page i am currently working on? can you give me an example code maybe?

Comment: the table row must have an ID and set the property runat="server" of the table row

Answer (score -1):

**HTML MARKUP**

I have created an empty table to append the row-cell from the code behind

```
    <table id="table1" runat="server">
   </table>
```

**CODE BEHIND SNIPPET**

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs  e){

    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow tr = new HtmlTableRow();
    //setting the style of a table row using the Attributes property
    tr.Attributes.Add("style", "width:500px; background-color:red");
    HtmlTableCell tc = new HtmlTableCell();
    tc.InnerHtml = "this is a test";
    tr.Controls.Add(tc);
    this.table1.Controls.Add(tr);
```

}

Hope this works for you.

Comment: well i have this right now: 
 System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow row = DeferredTaxesRollforwardControl1.FindControl("tblTempDiff") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow; 
        row.Attributes.Add("style", "width:500px; background-color:red");

        row.Cells[0].Visible = true;
        row.Cells[1].Visible = true;

Comment: but it doesnt seem to change the width of the row. sorry about the formatting.

Comment: @user1319424, this is a weird behavior, I've tested with 3 major browsers but all with the same result.

Comment: why the downvoter post a better explanation, How to set width of a html tablerow in C# instead downvote.